# Buttons and text are overlapping

Tags: html, css, button, overlapping

I'm just working on a project and cant figure out what is going on with my buttons. I have text divs below the buttons, but for some reasons they keep overlapping. Just wondering if anyone knows a quick fix? I tried putting a wrapper around the two buttons and setting that to display: block, but that still didn't work. Picture and code below:

```css
.hourlyButtonContainer {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.dailyButtonContainer {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}

#hourlyButton,
#dailyButton {
  color: #7E8959;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}

.displayContainer {
  display: block;
}

.displayContainer>div {
  display: inline-block;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  *display: inline;
  /* For IE7 */
  zoom: 1;
  /* Trigger hasLayout */
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.nextHoursContainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

#popTrailsNextHours {
  color: #7E8959;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #7E8959;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hourlyButtonContainer">
  <button id="hourlyButton" v-on:click="hourlySelected()">HOURLY</button>
</div>
<div class="dailyButtonContainer">
  <button id="dailyButton" v-on:click="dailySelected()">DAILY</button>
</div>
<div class="displayContainer">
  <div>LIVE</div>
  <div>1 PM</div>
  <div>3 PM</div>
  <div>5 PM</div>
</div>
<div class="displayContainer">
  <div>SVG</div>
  <div>SVG</div>
  <div>SVG</div>
  <div>SVG</div>
</div>
<div class="displayContainer">
  <div>Not busy</div>
  <div>Usually as busy as it gets</div>
  <div>usually a little busy</div>.
  <div>usually not too busy</div>
</div>
<div class="nextHoursContainer">
  <button id="popTrailsNextHours">NEXT 48 HOURS</button>
</div>
```

*** The 'hourly' and 'daily' should be above the other text [Image of overlap]

Image of overlap

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `position: absolute;`?

Comment: That was it, thank you!